# How can I ORDER BY a variable?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I don't know why it's not working... I'm trying to "order by" a created variable like this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(banfrom), '%d/%m/%Y') as time FROM ab_list WHERE time = '24/08/2013' ORDER BY banfrom DESC LIMIT 0,50");
```

Or,

```
   $hr = date('d/m/Y');
   mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(banfrom), '%d/%m/%Y') as time FROM       ab_list WHERE time = '$hr' ORDER BY banfrom DESC LIMIT 0,50");
```

Comment: Well, what is going wrong? "It's not working" is too vague to expect much help.

Comment: Reading minds is not my super power :)

Comment: Sorry.. When I do that I recive a mysql error like mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in

Comment: Basic debugging... `echo mysql_error()` after the query.

Comment: Sorry guys I dont speak english very well, But my problem is that I cant find using WHERE time = '24/08/2013' and if I do the echo , its echo "24/08/2013"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the variable `$hr` is in the format `%d/%m/%Y`, you can use `having` instead of `where` to filter the records.

```
mysql_query("SELECT *,DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(banfrom), '%d/%m/%Y') as time 
             FROM ab_list 
             HAVING time = '$hr' 
             ORDER BY banfrom DESC 
             LIMIT 0,50");
```

The reason to use `HAVING` and not `WHERE` in this case is because `time` is computed column.

Comment: Ohh Its working fine now.. Now Im learning more and more php.. Thanks for all :DDD

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are using an `ALIAS` in the `WHERE` clause that was created on the same level of the `SELECT` clause. There are two ways to make it working,

**One**, using the calculated column directly in the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(banfrom), '%d/%m/%Y') = '24/08/2013'
```

**Second**, using a subquery

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   (put your whole query here) a
WHERE  a.time = '24/08/2013'
```

`WHERE` cannot use `ALIAS` because in the *SQL Order of Operation* the `WHERE` clause is executed before the `SELECT` clause. Here's the list of order of operations:

- FROM clause
- WHERE clause
- GROUP BY clause
- HAVING clause
- SELECT clause (*Alias is created here*)
- ORDER BY clause